# get difference in seconds from firebase timestamp and current time in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, nsdate

I want to get difference between timestamp received from firebase observer and current time in seconds. I tried

```
self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
if snap.hasChild("timestamp") { 

                    if let object = snap.value as? [String: Any] {

                        for element in object {

                            if element.key == "timestamp" {

                                if let lastTime = element.value as? TimeInterval {

                                     // Do your stuff
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
              }
        })
```

But lastTime is negative value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found for a timestamp set up in Firebase using `ServerValue.timestamp()` :

```
if let lastTime = element.value as? TimeInterval {
    // Cast the value to an NSTimeInterval
    // and divide by 1000 to get seconds.
    print(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: lastTime/1000))
}
```

Comment: Don't use Foundation Data types in Swift, when they have native Swift alternatives. Use `TimeInterval` and `Date`.

Comment: I tried the same, but it does not worked for me because lastTime has negative time stamp.